# mysql 8 high availability with drbd, corosync and pacemaker

Tags: mysql, high-availability, mysql-8.0

I would like to implement High Availability for MySQL8, is this version supported by drbd, heartbeat, corosync, pacemaker? I've looked around online to that regard but there isn't much information about MySQL8. What is the ideal HA cluster for MySQL8?

Comment: DRBD only protects against disk failure; what about all the other things that can fail?

Answer (score 3):

Those days I won't recommend you to use these technique to MySQL HA. I love pacemaker but it's not suitable for datbases are those are much more complex.

I would recommend you to use MySQL InnoDB Cluster that handles everything, from orchestration to routing. It provides you everything you need built-in, split-brain prevention, quorum, data consistency, automatic data provisioning, ...

Take a look at :

- https://www.slideshare.net/Grypyrg/mysql-innodb-cluster-new-features-in-80-releases-best-practices
- https://www.slideshare.net/Grypyrg/mysql-database-architectures-innodb-replicaset-cluster-220070786
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7pFwxiglHc

Regards,